# Not a statement (for loop)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am getting errors in my Java code. 
Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
        int count = 1;
        int dividend1=(int)Math.abs(dividend);
        int divisor1=(int)Math.abs(divisor);
        for(int i=0;i<=dividend1;i+divisor1){
            if((i+divisor1)<=dividend1)
                count++;
            if((i+divisor1)>dividend1)
                break;
        }
        if(dividend<0 && divisor>0||divisor<0 && dividend>0){
            System.out.print("-");
            return count;
        }
        else 
            return count;
    }
}
```

The error is shown in for loop, saying this: 
prog.java:6: error: not a statement
        for(int i=0;i<=dividend1;i+divisor1)

What is the problem?

Comment: This wouldn't cause that error, but surely you want `i+=divisor1` instead of `i+divisor1` or something similar? `i+divisor1` alone doesn't do anything.

Comment: `i+divisor1` is not a statement, it's an expression.

Comment: My update goes like this: I want to increment i to i+divisor1. In for loop, i should be changed to i+divisor1

Comment: We often write i++ for updating the values in for loop, how can I write i+divisor1 then, without getting the error?

Comment: `i+=divisor1` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong for the for loop, the last part needs to be an assignment
change
 for(int i=0;i<=dividend1;i+divisor1)
to something like:
 for(int i=0;i<=dividend1;i=i+divisor1)

Answer (score 0):

change i+divisor1 to i+=divisor1 if you want to increment i by divisor1 value.

```
 public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
        int count = 1;
        int dividend1=(int)Math.abs(dividend);
        int divisor1=(int)Math.abs(divisor);
        for(int i=0;i<=dividend1;i+=divisor1){
            if((i+divisor1)<=dividend1)
                count++;
            if((i+divisor1)>dividend1)
                break;
        }
        if(dividend<0 && divisor>0||divisor<0 && dividend>0){
            System.out.print("-");
            return count;
        }
        else
            return count;
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work, If you want to increment i, use +=, not =+.

Comment: Sorry this is a typo.